# Mysqli inside namespace

Tags: php, methods, mysqli, namespaces

I need to use mysqli and prepared statements inside a namespace, this is working fine up until the point where I try and bind parameters, it connects find and prepare works but form there on I get an error saying call to undefined method.

I have already googled this and all that I could find from google is do

```
use Mysql;
```

This doesn't seem to help though. Stack overflow is my last resort.

This is the entire page:

```
<?php

namespace KrowdUp\Core; 

use Mysql;

class DatabaseConnect
{

private $user;
private $password;
private $database;
private $server;

//Variable for database connect
public $db;
//Variable for sql
public $dbSQL;
//Variable for db transaction
public $getData;
//Variable for db error
public $dbERROR;



public function __construct()
{

    $this->user = "user";
    $this->password = "password";
    $this->database = "databse";
    $this->server = "server";

    $this->db = new \mysqli($this->server, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database);

    if($this->db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
        //Handle error
    }

}

//Set the SQL
public function setSQL($sql) 
{

    $this->dbSQL = $sql;

}



//Check the SQL
public function checkSQL()
{

    if ($this->getData = $this->db->prepare($this->dbSQL)) {

        $this->dbERROR = 1;
        return 1;
        //Handle error properly

    } else {

        $this->dbERROR = 0;
        return 0;
        //Handle error properly

    }

}   

//Bind paramaters
public function bindParam($param) 
{

    $this->db->bind_param('i',$param);

}

}
```

Is this because I am doing something stupid and not noticing or am I missing something? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind_param is a function of mysqli_statement, not the mysqli connection

try

```
$this->getData->bind_param('i', $param);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php